# How can i run my embedded Shopify app locally

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

I created an embedded Shopify app and i am trying to run it on localhost.

When i install it on `http://www.localhost:3000/login`
[image] it redirects me to the admin panel even though i set my redirect link to `http://localhost:3000/auth/shopify/callback`

I want to know how i can get it working locally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use a service like:

- [Forward](https://forwardhq.com/) (EDIT: Forward has shutdown as of Jan 1, 2020)
- [Ngrok](https://ngrok.com/)

Those services allow you to have a url on internet that creates a tunnel to your localhost so you can test your webhooks, embedded pages and proxy pages with Shopify.

You have to configure the url that the service you choose gives to you on your Shopify App using the Shopify Partner portal.

I personally use Forward. With this service you get a domain like yourname.fwd.wf so you can have https://youname.fwd.wf/auth/shopify/callback and it will create a tunnel to your localhost.

Comment: @Ernesto Can you please answer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47432209/shopify-get-shop-domain-inside-a-app

Comment: as of 1st Jan 2020, Forward has shut down

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve that without using ngrok-like service with the combination of a proxi and a fake dns record.

1. add [fake domin](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/27350/beginner-geek-how-to-edit-your-hosts-file/) in the System32\drivers\etc\hosts file like this:

   `127.0.0.1 www.<your fake domain>.com`
2. run local proxy service like [npm local-ssl-proxy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/local-ssl-proxy):

   `local-ssl-proxy --source 443 --target 3000`
3. whitelist your fake domain in the Shopify app settings.
   [image]
4. add Env variable in the env file:

   `NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0`

the above worked for me with a Shopify AppProvider

Comment: steps 1-2 can be replaced with https://www.npmjs.com/package/hiproxy

Comment: This worked for me. I tried hiproxy but that was badly documented and was too frustated to work on figuring it.